# Best place on screen to put drag and drop

Tags: gui-design, drag-n-drop, placement, position

I'm having a set of items and a set of groups, The items can be dragged and dropped onto the groups to make a different combinations as user wants.

Now my question is which is the best place on screen to put these drag and drops.
I mean

items list and then groups

or

groups and then items list

Here my groups section occupies 2/3rd of the screen width and has some additional information about the items validity in the screen and some other details.

Please help which placements is better and why?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots or mockups? You can create a mockup using built-in Balsamiq tools when you edit the question. Also, please specify in the visuals what exactly is the problem you're solving because I can see several very different solutions as of the current description.

Comment: An estimation of the number of items and groups is interesting to know, as well. And do you want to distribute all items to groups, effectively emptying the item list?

Comment: @virtualnobi: no, Not all the items need to be distributed among the groups

Answer (score 3):

### Items on the Left / Groups on the Right

[Users scan from left to right](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/) so interactions should follow suit.  Especially in your case where the target groups take up most of the screen putting the list of draggable items on the left is the way to go.

Be sure to test this with your users as the opposite would be true when targeting countries that read right to left.

[image: drag left to right]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but in the UI drag and drop is done only when required item is not in the expected group or new item is to be added into the group and there are other actions that can be performed on the items present in the group as well. So if I follow the placement you have suggested then will it satisfy my above statement. Please help me on this part also.

Comment: Post a screen shot and I'll take a look.